# Voiceover iOS | swiping right when in the last element of the page

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

Using Voiceover in iOS, when I am in the last element of the page then swiping right of the web page won't go to anywhere but it is stuck on the last element, rereading it.

Is it expected to go back to the header of the page after swiping right on the last element? or this behavior is expected in iOS device?

Comment: That's how VoiceOver works. It stops on the last element. You can use a 4-finger single tap on the top half of your screen to move the focus to the first element. A 4-finger single tap on the bottom half of your screen to move the focus to the last element.